# SSRS 2005 - How to tell when Group has changed

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-grouping

Is there a way to determine when a Grouping has changed in SSRS 2005?

For example, if you are grouping on OrderID, displaying the Order Header info, and the details are the Order_Items etc... Is there an event to check for to tell when the "new" OrderID has appeared?

Are you able to somehow compare the current OrderID to the previous OrderID in the group?

I have multiple groupings in a report, and this group in particular is the 3rd group, and on the Grouping change, I want to make the border of the Group Header solid.  There are certain occasions depending how the groups change, the boarder is left as "None" and it looks odd in the report.

Edit: (Here is an Image Example)

[image: Example]

I have managed it so far by adding an additional row to another grouping, and making the row height .03125.  It gives off the desired appearance, but I thought there was a way to tell when the grouping changed.  Maybe grouping row number = 0 or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres not really an event, but you should know that when you create a group you can include a group footer within the group.  The groups details ends once it hits the footer of the group.

I personally like to use this to create row border style (bottom) with a line to get a nice effect allowing me to see when the group is complete.

Something to this effect:

[image]

Comment: Im marking this as the answer, after much looking, you are correct there isn't and event :(